# Using the directory name 'vendor', for non-vendored files

Tags: go, goland

On a project that I am working on, we have a directory for each domain model (to segregate repositories etc). The name of domain model is singular.
Now we're adding another model called vendor
Goland (IDE) marks it has go vendor directory (excluded)...

Overall, GO wouldn't pick it up as go vendor directory, but still in goland its marked as go vendor directory. We plan to have this directory in to places, one inside /internal, and another inside /cmd.

What do you suggest here, should we use it as "vendor" or find an alternate?

An alternate is that we refactor all the packages to have an 's' at the end, e.g. user -> users, shop -> shops, and vendor -> vendors. But it doesn't look right.

Comment: Folders like vendor and testdata have special meaning and using them for anything other is a bad idea. Don't do that.

Comment: Are you using Go's "vendoring" feature?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the `vendor` package with some alternative words.

As far as I know, there is no obvious way to work around the `vendor` naming convention.

And it's not worth doing so, to change a language's specification for a unified naming.